# How Can I change my app in iTunes connect to specific in my country?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is my first time to upload my app to itunesconnect. However, I couldn't manage to find my app in my device's App Store. I Realised my app although available for all countries, but mainly in US Store. How can I change the store to my country store which is Malaysia(MY)? So that I can search my app in my country's App Store? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just ask programming questions on Stackoverflow. You can post such kind of question though here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask or https://forums.developer.apple.com

If you want to make your app available in specific countries, you can find the settings on ItunesConnect `Pricing and Availability`.

If you want to change the country of your Apple account, you can make a new one or follow the instruction here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389

Comment: okay thanks for the advices, I really don't know have such websites to ask.